# Unchangeable digits in textbox value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to set readonly '09' digit in my input element I mean user can type in `input textbox` but cant edit or remove 09 in it and it is constant . The following code is only for 9 digit. Could anyone help me out with this?

```js
$('#PhoneField').keyup(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val()[0] != '9')
    $(this).val('9' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="PhoneField" class="phoneBox" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: can you be more precise and show us a complete code with HTML also

Comment: @TemaniAfif post editted

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i mentioned i didnt say a readonly field i said some unchangeble digit in textbox

Comment: Now you've edited it makes a little more sense. What you're trying to do is possible, but is a real pain, and confusing for your users. I'd suggest splitting the `09` in to it's own readonly input, and have you users type the remaining 8 digits in its own box. You can then concatenate the two values when needed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you help me please to correct my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may do this :

```js
$("#PhoneField").keydown(function(e) {
var v=$(this).val();
var f=this;
setTimeout(function () {
    if(f.value.indexOf('09') !== 0) {
        $(f).val(v);
    } 
}, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="PhoneField" value="09" class="phoneBox" maxlength="10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#PhoneField').keyup(function(e) {
  if (!$(this).val().startsWith("09","0")){
    $(this).val('09');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="PhoneField" value="09" class="phoneBox" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: your solution is wrong, we are able to insert input before the '09'. Also try to insert a number between the 0 and 9, you will see a strange result

Comment: seems fine now ;)